# How to check protoc version if same as libprotobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have protoc --version:

```
libprotoc 3.12.4
```

But locate libprotbuf:

```
locate libprotobuf        
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.23
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.23.0.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.23
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.23.0.4
```

I am confused here, how to check if 23 == 3.12??

Answer (score 1):

The number after the library name is called `SOVERSION`, which stands for shared object version. It is changed when incompatible changes are made to the library.

For the protobuf `3.x` series, `SOVERSION` equals `11 + x`, as defined [in update_version.py](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/520c601c99012101c816b6ccc89e8d6fc28fdbb8/update_version.py#L64-L74).

Protobuf 3.12 should therefore be `libprotobuf.so.23`, like you have.

Another way is to check `PROTOBUF_VERSION` define in [Makefile.am](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v3.12.4/src/Makefile.am) of the specific version. In GitHub you can select the version tag from the dropdown menu at the top.